# F# casting to type that is not known at compile time

Tags: .net, reflection, casting, f#

How to cast given obj list.

```
let l = [1. :> obj; 2. :> obj]
```

back to float list when original type (in this case float) **is not known at compile time**?

I already tried (to show how little I know about this :)):

```
let t = (l |> List.head).GetType();
l |> List.map (fun e -> e :?> t)
```

Which fails terribly.

and

```
let castMe (ty : Type) (arr : obj list)  =
        let m = typeof<Enumerable>.GetMethod("Cast")
        let m = m.MakeGenericMethod([|ty|])
        m.Invoke(null, [|arr|]) :?> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<_>

let t = (l |> List.head).GetType();
l |> castMe t;;
```

Which fails with:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to
>   have generic type
>       val it : Generic.IEnumerable<'_a>     Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if
>   you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

=============================================

Edit:

I will try explain what I am trying to achieve and what I have so far because maybe I am not taking the right approach at all.

This is the structure I use for saving the data I am providing the types for.

```
type public InnerData(query, table) =
    ...
    member __.Data = data       // map <string, obj list>
    member __.Headers = headers // Dictionary <string, Type>
```

Here is the constructor of my type provider.

```
ty.AddMember(ProvidedConstructor([], InvokeCode = fun [] -> <@@ InnerData(queryParam, tableNameParam) :> obj @@>))
```

And here is how I define properties that represent dictionary keys. Take a look at the comment.

```
do mdsTy.DefineStaticParameters([tableNameParam; queueryParam], fun tyName [| :? string as tableNameParam; :? string as queryParam |] ->
        let ty = ProvidedTypeDefinition(
                        asm, 
                        ns, 
                        tyName, 
                        baseType = Some(typeof<obj>))

        let mdsInner = MdsData(mdsQueryParam, tableNameParam)

        for header in mdsInner.Headers do
            let columnName = header.Key
            let columnType = header.Value

            let arrayType = typedefof<IEnumerable<_>>.MakeGenericType(typeof<obj>)
            // This works, but returns obj list. I would like to return a list of columnType that represents the downcasted version of arraytype.

            let property = ProvidedProperty(columnName, arrayType,
                                GetterCode = fun [innerType] -> <@@ ((%%innerType:obj) :?> InnerData).Data.[columnName] @@>)
            ty.AddMember(property)
```

Here I tried to cast the data using aforementioned methods (reflection and :?>) but without any luck.

Comment: Assume for a minute that you can cast to "runtime types", what do you plan on doing with this value? You can't call a method or access data with the `.` operator since the type is known at runtime not compile time. Are you going to use reflection to invoke methods or properties on the value? If you are, there's no reason to cast it.

Comment: I am trying to create F# type provider that would provide from Dictionary<string, List<object>> something like F# type with those dictionary lists as type members.

Comment: @WesleyWiser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923567/f-type-provider-use-case (If this is completely unrelated let me know Klark and I'' delete this)

Comment: @RubenBartelink Thanks, the background for this question is helpful.

Comment: It seems to me that your type provider just need to generate a type which represents the Dictionary<string, object>. Reading through the tutorials [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034.aspx) gives me the impression that you don't need to cast to the runtime time like you are trying to do. Which part of implementing the type provider are you getting stuck on?

Comment: @RubenBartelink Yes, this is completely related.

Comment: @Wesley Wiser Please look at the edit I just made. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no syntax for this, since as Wesley Wiser notes there's nothing that you could do with such an expression anyway.  However, since you're dealing with `Expr` values, you can use the `Expr.Coerce` method to create an expression tree equivalent to what you want.

Comment: Can you please point me to some resource on how to use Expr.Coerce for this?

Comment: @Klark - As an example, `Expr.Coerce(<@ box 1.0 @>, typeof<float>)` is roughly equivalent to `<@@ box 1.0 :?> float @@>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you initially asked for using a helper class that you invoke via reflection:

```
type CastHelper<'t>() =
    static member Go(xs : obj list) : 't list =
        xs |> List.map (fun x -> x :?> 't)

let castList (xs : obj list) : obj =

    let typ =
        match xs with
        | [] -> failwithf "Can't cast an empty list"
        | x::xs -> x.GetType()

    let doCast = typedefof<CastHelper<_>>.MakeGenericType([|typ|])
                                         .GetMethod("Go")

    doCast.Invoke(null, [|box xs|])
```

For example with your sample data:

```
> let xs = [1.0 :> obj ; 2.0 :> obj];;

val xs : obj list = [1.0; 2.0]

> let ys = castList xs;;

val ys : obj = [1.0; 2.0]

> xs.GetType().FullName;;

val it : string =
  "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"

> ys.GetType().FullName;;

val it : string =
  "Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.Double, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"
```

i.e. the result has a dynamic type of `float list` (but a static type of `obj`), whereas the original input had a dynamic type of `obj list`.

To make worthwhile use of the result you'll need something that cares about the distinction, but such code can certainly exist.

Comment: Nice. But is it possible to get a static type of float list too?

Comment: The only way is via reflection, or an explicit type test if you specifically want to look for `float list` - those are the two ways you get from a dynamic type to a static type. Inside `Go` in `CastHelper`, the result does have the static type of `float list`, so one option is to make that method longer and have it do what you actually want to do with the list.